# Атоматическая отправка письма после оплаты

Tags: javascript, email

Такая проблема, хочу чтоб после оплаты на сайте отправлялось письмо на почту с купленными товарами, но не знаю как это реализовать.

```js
const checkPayment = async (paymentId: string) => {
    try {
      const data = await checkPaymentFx({
        url: '/payment/info',
        paymentId,
      })

      if (data.status === 'succeeded') {
        resetCart()
        return
      }

      sessionStorage.removeItem('paymentId')
    } catch (error) {
      console.log((error as Error).message)
      // resetCart()
    }
  }

  const resetCart = async () => {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('paymentId')
    await removeFromCartFx(`/shopping-cart/all/${user.userId}`)
    setShoppingCart([])
  }
```

здесь идет проверка оплаты и после очистка корзины, надо после проверки оплаты отправить письмо на почту с куплеными товарами

Comment: С клиента это не получится. Отправка писем идет с сервера. На сервер делайте запрос на отправку сообщения.

Comment: можно ли такое реализовать через emailjs?

Comment: Если у вас nodejs в качестве бэка, то можно. Данный пакет как раз для этого и сделан. А вот получится ли с его помощью достучаться до email сервера, это уже второй вопрос...

Comment: Как вариант - найти сервис который по запросу может отправлять письма на указанные адреса и с указанным текстом... Тогда такое можно будет реализовать и без своего почтового сервера.

Comment: https://formspree.io/ решение для статических сайтов

Comment: немного не то, формы не будет а отправлять будет автоматом после оплаты, собирать данные корзины, отправлять и чистить ее, но не знаю как это реализовать, думал через useState но пока не придумал, сделаю через emailjs, так как форма на сайте уже работает с ним, и создать новый шаблон не проблема